# Android: GSON with Fedor's LazyList

Tags: android, gson, lazylist

I've just implemented GSON to Fedor's LazyLoading ListView. That means the app saves the downloaded images and texts from the web to the external storage though an ImageLoader class.

and I wonder why how to make the listview accessible without an internet connection?
The app already succesfully saves the cache data into the SD Card, and now how to call those files? So when there's no internet, it will call the data (text and Image) from the SD Card.

Thanks. I'm open to any kind of solution

here's my ListView Class:

```
public class ProjectsList extends Activity {
        ListView lstTest;

        ProjectAdapter arrayAdapter;

        ArrayList<Project> prjcts=null;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.projects_list);

            //Initialize ListView
            lstTest= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstText);

            prjcts = new ArrayList<Project>();

            arrayAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(ProjectsList.this, R.layout.listitems,prjcts,ProjectsList.this);

                lstTest.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                if (isOnline())
                {
            WebService webService = new WebService("http://liebenwald.spendino.net/admanager/dev/android/projects.json");

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("var", "");

            String response = webService.webGet("", params);

            try
            {
                Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Project>>(){}.getType();
                List<Project> lst= new Gson().fromJson(response, collectionType);


                for(Project l : lst)
                {
                    prjcts.add(l);
                    ConstantData.projectsList.add(l);
                }

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
           }


            lstTest.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                    Intent care = new Intent(ProjectsList.this, ProjectDetail.class);
                    care.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position",position);
                    startActivity(care);
                }
            });

        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            yAdapter.imageLoader.stopThread();
            lstTest.setAdapter(null);
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        protected boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                     }
                 });
                return false;
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your getBitmap() method in ImageLoader class to the below one

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String urlString)
{
    String filename = String.valueOf(urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    // from web
    try
    {
        if(!f.exists())
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream is = new URL(urlString).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Globals.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        }
        else
        {               
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        BitmapDrawable mDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);
        return mDrawable.getBitmap();
    }
}
```

But if there is no connection how you will come to know that which image is to be loaded at which position?

Comment: Thx. I might try that. That I don't know very clear, maybe you can have a look at edited question above, I posted my ListView class. And what do I need to add inside my ListView class?

Comment: Thats what I have written in the end of my answer, by the way what you do if the its online then save the whole JSON file in sdcard and the next time if its not online then use this file from sdcard I might be worong its just an idea as I had no exp of JSON

Comment: Cache the JSON response in appPreferences as a string.  Replace it when you're connected, use it when you're not.

Comment: @T0X1C that might could be an option, and then it loads the image from the SD Card instead of the web? or what? Anyway where should I declare the 'context' on your code above?

Comment: @Bill Mote can you post an answer with an example using my code maybe? Thanks.. just tell me what you need

Comment: Nothing special to do.  You're already checking to see if you have connectivity.  You should probably set a flag that can be used by your other methods.  When you go to get your JSON string just check the connectivity flag.  If you don't have connectivity then read the result from application preferences or a local db.  If you do have connectivity then read it from the web service.  In the event that you don't have connectivity and nothing cached display an error ;)

Comment: Thanks, gotta try with the local db first